# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deviceXDPI' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I am new Lightning Experience, I implemented map using **`leaf_let`** when run the code found following error.

> ```
>    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deviceXDPI' of undefined
> throws at /resource/leaflet/leaflet.js:4:6978
>     at Error (native)
>     at Iy.<anonymous> (https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_prod.js:153:22)
>     at new Iy (https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_prod.js:153:296)
>     at Object.handler_aura_systemError (https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LpC4IEwqmgPMoQPKh1C1EA%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22E%22%7D/app.js:5057:225)
>     at https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LpC4IEwqmgPMoQPKh1C1EA%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22E%22%7D/app.js:3512:244
>     at Object.handleEvent (https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LpC4IEwqmgPMoQPKh1C1EA%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22E%22%7D/app.js:3511:338)
>     at handleDelegatedEvent (https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LpC4IEwqmgPMoQPKh1C1EA%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22E%22%7D/app.js:3509:72)
>     at G.oc (https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_prod.js:274:169)
>     at https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_prod.js:228:72
>     at https://growerslightning-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_prod.js:264:424
> ```

Any suggestion will be thankful.

Comment: isnt that a leafletjs issue?

Comment: You could use your browser's debugger to set a breakpoint at line 6978 of leaflet.js to figure out what value is undefined. Pretty impossible for anyone here to be able to help with the question as it stands.

Comment: This issue is specific to Leaflet.js combined with Locker Service - known issue that already has a fix in the next patch.  In addition there is another unresolved issue with LS combined with Leadlet that causes the map tiles to not be positioned correctly that is under investigation. In Develoer Edition orgs you can disable the critical update for Locker Service under Setup.